# WiX Bootstrapper issues installing prerequisites for Outlook add-in, error 0x80091007

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I'm trying to use WiX Bootstrapper project to install prerequisites for my Outlook add-in MSI. It needs two things:

- [.NET Framework 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21)
- [Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56961)

So I created a WiX Bootstrapper project in Visual Studio and I'm doing the bundle identification and installation as such:

```
  <Bundle Name="BootstrapperTestApp" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="<company>" UpgradeCode="<guid>"
          AboutUrl="https://example.com" Copyright="Copyright (C) 2020 by example.com">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <util:RegistrySearch Id="idOffice2007Installed" Variable="OFFICE2007INST"
                        Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\InstallRoot" Result="exists" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="isVSTORInstalled" Variable="VSTOR"
                         Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R" Result="exists" />
    
    <Chain>
      <!-- We need .NET 3.5 to be installed -->
      <ExePackage SourceFile="Source\dotNetFx35setup.exe" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes"
                  DisplayName=".NET Framework 3.5"
                  DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK35"
                  InstallCondition="NOT NETFRAMEWORK35" />

      <!-- We need VSTO 2010 Tools for Office Runtime for .NET to be installed. (Note that we need it only for Office 2007) -->
      <ExePackage SourceFile="Source\vstor_redist.exe" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes"
                  DisplayName="Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime 3.5"
                  DownloadUrl="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="VSTOR"
                  InstallCondition="OFFICE2007INST AND NOT VSTOR" />
      
      <!-- Our actual add-in MSI -->
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SourceMSI)" Vital="yes" />

    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
```

I have 3 issues that come up, so I'd appreciate any help:

1. I can't seem to find a download link for .NET 3.5 to use here. Is the link I'm using above the correct one?
2. If I build and run this bootstrapper MSI in a VM that has .NET 3.5 installed, my bootstrapper still begins downloading and installing it. Why?
3. Lastly, if I let it run, when it switches to installing `VSTO 2010 Tools for Office Runtime`, it tries for 3 times and then fails with an error code `0x80091007`. I'm attaching the full log for that:

- 

```
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.2 (Build 9200: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BootstrapperTestApp.exe, cmdline: ''
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\BootstrapperTestApp_20200702141743.log'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BootstrapperTestApp.exe'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'BootstrapperTestApp'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i000: Setting numeric variable 'OFFICE2007INST' to value 1
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VSTOR' to value 0
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK35' evaluates to false.
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i052: Condition 'VSTOR' evaluates to false.
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i101: Detected package: dotNetFx35setup.exe, state: Absent, cached: None
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i101: Detected package: vstor_redist.exe, state: Absent, cached: None
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i101: Detected package: TestAppInstaller.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:43]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Install
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i052: Condition 'NOT NETFRAMEWORK35' evaluates to true.
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: dotNetFx35setup.exe
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotNetFx35setup.exe' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\BootstrapperTestApp_20200702141743_0_dotNetFx35setup.exe.log'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i052: Condition 'OFFICE2007INST AND NOT VSTOR' evaluates to true.
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: vstor_redist.exe
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vstor_redist.exe' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\BootstrapperTestApp_20200702141743_1_vstor_redist.exe.log'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_TestAppInstaller.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\BootstrapperTestApp_20200702141743_2_TestAppInstaller.msi_rollback.log'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_TestAppInstaller.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\BootstrapperTestApp_20200702141743_2_TestAppInstaller.msi.log'
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i201: Planned package: dotNetFx35setup.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i201: Planned package: vstor_redist.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i201: Planned package: TestAppInstaller.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:17:45]i300: Apply begin
[0EAC:0778][2020-07-02T14:17:47]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0EAC:0778][2020-07-02T14:17:51]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0EAC:0778][2020-07-02T14:17:51]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}\.be\BootstrapperTestApp.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}\BootstrapperTestApp.exe'
[0EAC:0778][2020-07-02T14:17:51]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}, version: 1.0.0.0
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:17:51]w343: Prompt for source of package: dotNetFx35setup.exe, payload: dotNetFx35setup.exe, path: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\dotNetFx35setup.exe
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:17:51]i338: Acquiring package: dotNetFx35setup.exe, payload: dotNetFx35setup.exe, download from: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:32]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotNetFx35setup.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotNetFx35setup.exe, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\B0CA05C12EBB9A3610206BAD7F219E02B7873CBD\dotNetFx35setup.exe.
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:32]w343: Prompt for source of package: vstor_redist.exe, payload: vstor_redist.exe, path: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\vstor_redist.exe
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:32]i338: Acquiring package: vstor_redist.exe, payload: vstor_redist.exe, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:40]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vstor_redist.exe
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:40]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: vstor_redist.exe
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:40]e310: Failed to verify payload: vstor_redist.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vstor_redist.exe, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:40]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: vstor_redist.exe
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:40]e314: Failed to cache payload: vstor_redist.exe from working path: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}\vstor_redist.exe, error: 0x80091007.
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:40]e349: Application requested retry of payload: vstor_redist.exe, encountered error: 0x80091007. Retrying...
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:40]w343: Prompt for source of package: vstor_redist.exe, payload: vstor_redist.exe, path: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\vstor_redist.exe
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:43]i338: Acquiring package: vstor_redist.exe, payload: vstor_redist.exe, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:51]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vstor_redist.exe
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:51]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: vstor_redist.exe
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:51]e310: Failed to verify payload: vstor_redist.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vstor_redist.exe, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:18:51]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: vstor_redist.exe
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:51]e314: Failed to cache payload: vstor_redist.exe from working path: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}\vstor_redist.exe, error: 0x80091007.
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:51]e349: Application requested retry of payload: vstor_redist.exe, encountered error: 0x80091007. Retrying...
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:51]w343: Prompt for source of package: vstor_redist.exe, payload: vstor_redist.exe, path: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\vstor_redist.exe
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:18:54]i338: Acquiring package: vstor_redist.exe, payload: vstor_redist.exe, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:19:02]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vstor_redist.exe
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:19:02]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: vstor_redist.exe
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:19:02]e310: Failed to verify payload: vstor_redist.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vstor_redist.exe, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:19:02]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: vstor_redist.exe
[0C54:0428][2020-07-02T14:19:02]e314: Failed to cache payload: vstor_redist.exe from working path: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}\vstor_redist.exe, error: 0x80091007.
[0EAC:0D58][2020-07-02T14:19:02]i351: Removing cached package: dotNetFx35setup.exe, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\B0CA05C12EBB9A3610206BAD7F219E02B7873CBD\
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:19:02]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[0EAC:0778][2020-07-02T14:19:02]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}
[0EAC:0778][2020-07-02T14:19:02]i352: Removing cached bundle: {ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{ec724e25-c6e3-47ba-91a3-8e894c092324}\
[0C54:09AC][2020-07-02T14:19:02]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80091007, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```